# Python combining information in a list of lists using indexes in a tuple

Tags: python

I have a main data source consisting of a list of lists and a dictionary of tuples that indexes the information I need from the main data source.

I would like to use the dictionary of tuples to index each entry from the main data source and create a new list with this information.

I have created the code below but the the error says "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not generator"

I have searched for how to iterate through each list in a list of lists but have not found the solution.

Any suggestions welcome.

```
#List of data
MyDat = [['round', 'square', 'oblong', 'circle', 'round'],['orange','orange','purple','green','yellow'],    ['rough','rough','smooth','rough','smooth']]

#Tuples required to create new list of variable combinations 
tupDict = {"stage1": (0,2), "stage2": (1,)}

newList = []

for i in tupDict:
        newList.append(MyDat[(x for x in tupDict[i])])

print(newList)
```

The new list should create a new list of lists of the columns selected in the MyDat. For example:

```
Stage1: (0,2)
```

would create this list

```
[['round', 'square', 'oblong', 'circle', 'round'], ['rough','rough','smooth','rough','smooth']]
```

Comment: Looks like I and @MdMahfuzurRahman answering different questions. Can you add what you wish to see in newList? (actual data, that should be there after run valid code on data in example)

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks yes this was a typo. It should read 'dictionary of tuples in the second paragraph also'. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try like this:

```
MyDat = [['round', 'square', 'oblong', 'circle', 'round'],['orange','orange','purple','green','yellow'],    ['rough','rough','smooth','rough','smooth']]

#Tuples required to create new list of variable combinations 
tupDict = {"stage1": (0,2), "stage2": (1,)}

newList = []

for i in tupDict:
    newList.extend([MyDat[x] for x in tupDict[i]])

print(newList)
```

I just changed this line:

```
newList.append(MyDat[(x for x in tupDict[i])])
```

To this:

```
newList.extend([MyDat[x] for x in tupDict[i]])
```

In this line: `newList.append(MyDat[(x for x in tupDict[i])])` you are using a `tuple` as a index of the `MyDat`. But `integer` is needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to achieve. I edited your answer however to reset the newList variable each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in tupDict:
    tmp = MyDat # temporary variable to store data by current index
    for x in tupDict[i]: # iterate over indexes in tuple
        tmp = tmp[ x ]   # set tmp to data by index

    newList.append( tmp ) #we finish iterating over index, now tmp hold value that we need
```

Also, I should mention, that order of elements in `newList`may vary, because `dict` don't save order of elements.

If you wish to have elements in `newList` in same order as you define in code, then you should use `OrderedDict` from `collections` module.